# Suppose that $a_n$, $b_n$ are such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n}{b_n} = \alpha$

Tags: real-analysis

***Problem:*** Suppose that $a_n$, $b_n$ are sequences of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n}{b_n} = \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, show that $b_n \rightarrow \infty$.

***Thoughts***: It seems that I could start with a proof by contradiction of 3 different cases where $b_n$ converges to a real number, or that it converges to negative infinity, and finally that it diverges. This seems like the wrong approach. Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the epsilon definition of the limits?

Comment: @Vik78 sorry my mistake edited.

Comment: Why did you accept a faulty answer?

Comment: @Did I was just going back to questions that I hadn't accepted and must have been careless. I rescinded the answer sorry about that.

Comment: Be aware that $a\in\mathbb{R_+}$ has to hold to deduct $b_n\to \infty$. Otherwise we can e.g. set $b_n = -a_n$.

Comment: @Sudix The problem includes assumptions that $a_n,b_n$ are sequences of positive numbers.  On the other hand, $\alpha = 0$ is possible and the statement still holds.

Answer (score 0):

if $b_n $ is bounded, given any arbitrary large $\epsilon$ we can find an $N$ such that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \ge \epsilon$ for some $n \ge N$. after ruling out $b_n$ being bounded, Only case remains is $b_n$ diverging. In this case we can always find a subsequnce of $b_n$ that is bounded, so $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ contains a subsequence that is going to  $\infty$, which is again a contradiction.